# JQuery get all elements with a certain class and remove a CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to remove a CSS property from all elements with a certain class. I tried this but it did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".TABlink").click(function(){
$('.TABlink').css('background-image','')
}); });
```

That is supposed to remove a background image from all elements with that class if one of them is clicked. Not working.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, maybe it doesn't like empty property value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".TABlink").click(function(){
    $('.TABlink').css('background-image','none');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`$('.TABlink').css('background-image', 'none');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but it might be useful for future viewers :
I had the same requirement, although with background-color. The following function worked for me fine :

```
$('.className').css('background-color','white');
```

I had to mention the new-color ('white'), specifying 'none' didn't work.